# Parâmetro inválido, MemoryStream

Tags: c#

Boa tarde pessoal, estou desenvolvendo um pequeno projeto em [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) que precisa apresentar uma imagem junto com uma receita e é a primeira vez que trabalho com imagem em banco de dados, eu já inseri a imagem no banco de dados. Já no projeto(`C#`) quando vou passar o parâmetro do tipo `MemoryStream` da erro:

> Parâmetro inválido.

```
var receitaP1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (receitaP1.Read())
{
    receita.CodReceita = Convert.ToInt16(receitaP1["codReceita"].ToString());
    receita.NomeReceita = receitaP1["nomeReceita"].ToString();
    receita.ModoPreparo = receitaP1["modoDePreparo"].ToString();
    receita.Tipo = receitaP1["nomeTipo"].ToString();

    byte[] imagem = (byte[]) receitaP1["imagem"];
    MemoryStream memoria = new MemoryStream(imagem);

    Image image = Image.FromStream(memoria); //"Memoria" >>> Erro: parametro invalido!

    receita.Imagem = image;
}
```

**Vejam só, já esta como position 0**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Insert no banco de dados:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: pode mostrar o stacktrace gerado?

Comment: É possível que o conteúdo do seu `byte[]` não tenha sido salvo como uma imagem válida, então? Só vejo essa alternativa para não estar funcionando. Testa converter o seu array de bytes para base64string (`var b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imagem);`) e usar um [conversor online](http://www.convertstring.com/pt_PT/EncodeDecode/Base64Decode) para confirmar que foi armazenada certinho.

Comment: mostre como está salvando a imagem no banco

Comment: Pronto, eu fiz o insert a partir de um exemplo que eu peguei na internet